# R lowess with repeated points

Tags: r

R's lowess function seems to produce some strange results when there are repeated points in the data frame.
In the below data frame for high jump performance in the 2016 Olympic Women's heptathlon high jump, two scored equal best.

```r
# Here is the data frame I'm working with
structure(list(rank = 1:29, lastname = c("Thiam", "Ennis-Hill", 
"Eaton", "Ikauniece-Admidina", "Schafer", "Johnson-Thompson", 
"Rodriguez", "Zsivoczky-Farkas", "Oeser", "Vetter", "Ida", "Nwaba", 
"Broersen", "Rath", "Aguilar", "Krizsan", "Williams", "Miller-Koch", 
"Visser", "Jones", "Dadic", "Klucinova", "Chefer", "Cachova", 
"Kasyanova", "Felix", "Yfantidou", "Fodorova", "Osazuwa"), hj = c(1.98, 
1.89, 1.86, 1.77, 1.83, 1.98, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.77, 1.77, 1.83, 
1.77, 1.74, 1.74, 1.77, 1.83, 1.8, 1.68, 1.89, 1.77, 1.8, 1.68, 
1.77, 1.77, 1.68, 1.65, 1.8, 1.77), pts_hj = c(1211L, 1093L, 
1054L, 941L, 1016L, 1211L, 1054L, 1054L, 1054L, 941L, 941L, 1016L, 
941L, 903L, 903L, 941L, 1016L, 978L, 830L, 1093L, 941L, 978L, 
830L, 941L, 941L, 830L, 795L, 978L, 941L), dvvb_hj = c(2.26375883781343, 
1.13834730130046, 0.763210122462812, -0.36220141405015, 0.388072943625158, 
2.26375883781343, 0.763210122462812, 0.763210122462812, 0.763210122462812, 
-0.36220141405015, -0.36220141405015, 0.388072943625158, -0.36220141405015, 
-0.737338592887804, -0.737338592887804, -0.36220141405015, 0.388072943625158, 
0.0129357647875044, -1.48761295056311, 1.13834730130046, -0.36220141405015, 
0.0129357647875044, -1.48761295056311, -0.36220141405015, -0.36220141405015, 
-1.48761295056311, -1.86275012940077, 0.0129357647875044, -0.36220141405015
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -29L))
```

The `hept$hj` and `hept$pts_hj` are arranged almost linearly.
Plotting the `lowess` gives a curve with a sharp bend.

```r
plot(hept$hj, hept$pts_hj)
lines(lowess(hept$hj, hept$pts_hj))
```

[lowess curve with unexpected sharp bend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPMRO.png)
Changing the "smoother span" gives the expected figure

```r
plot(hept$hj, hept$pts_hj)
lines(lowess(hept$hj, hept$pts_hj, f = 1/3))
```

[close to linear lowess curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCdiy.png)
Presumably it has something to do with repeated points because neither

```r
lines(lowess(jitter(hept$hj), jitter(hept$pts_hj)))
```

nor

```r
lines(lowess(hepthj$hj[hepthj$rank != 1] ~ hepthj$pts_hj[hepthj$rank != 1]))
```

produce the bend.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for `lowess` say that "Normally a local linear polynomial fit is used, but under some circumstances (see the file) a local constant fit can be used."  The file it is referring to is https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/lowess.doc.  I would guess the fact that your dataset is almost perfectly linear is causing some instability in the algorithm to switch to locally constant for the points on the right.

Using the more modern code in `loess()` avoids this problem:

```
loess(pts_hj ~ hj, data=hept)
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer for most people. But apparently loess() isn't necessarily better than lowess(). From https://support.bioconductor.org/p/2323: "On the other hand, 'loess' is much slower than 'lowess' and occasionally fails when 'lowess' succeeds, so both programs are kept in R." Apart from the code implementation, LOESS and LOWESS also seem to be mathematically slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has reasons to prefer `lowess()` over `loess()`, an alternative solution:

With this particular data set, we found it is reasonable to add another data point for [Ekaterina Voronina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2016_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Women%27s_heptathlon#High_jump).
That makes `lowess()` produce the expected result, even though the added data point is far from the problematic part of the lowess curve.

It seems that `lowess()` is picky with repeated data points in unpredictable ways.